# A single word - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

*A musician oft rehearsed

Together with his part reversed

But he was not himself as such

A single word - two's much too much*

Comment: Hopefully this one will take more than 15 minutes to solve, unlike the last attempt...

Comment: Is the last line a clue to do with the musician, or is it telling us that the answer is a single word?

Comment: The second line makes me think of [crab canons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_canon).

Comment: @BrentHackers a good question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The single word may be:

> Bachelor

A musician oft rehearsed

> Bach - a very popular composer 
>  
>  
>  Inspiration from Jonathan Allan

Together with his part reversed

> His part is his *'role'* & reversed is *'elor'*, which *'together with'* *'Bach'* makes *'Bachelor'*'
>  
>  From OP - Bach composed pieces (e.g. J. S. Bach's The Musical Offering) in crab canon and can rehearsed with the parts reversed, as they are often the same. This in essence is a hint to reach Bach within the puzzle itself.

But he was not himself as such

> Edit from OP's improvement
>  
>  Bach was not a bachelor! 
>  
>  Original - Concatenating above gives bachelor

A single word - two's much too much

> A bachelor is a single man (*'single word'* can be a 'word for single'). JS Bach was married twice, two wives being much too much to be a bachelor. Also 'two' (as in a twosome) is the antithesis of bachelordom.

Comment: We have a winner, (and have +1d and will accept this). Bits of the clue can be used twice (for instance per the crab canon stuff, Bach can rehearsed with the parts reversed, as they are often the same) - this was a hint for 'Bach'. Bach was not a bachelor (third line). Further (last line) Bach had two wives, so was certainly not a bachelor. And of course, most relevantly, **"Bachelor" is a single word, i.e. a word for being single**.

Comment: Very intricate and well composed puzzle - I added some updates from your response! (Feel free to edit too!.)

Comment: have done - you may need to accept it.

Comment: Accepted edit and Bach is a really suitable choice for role reversal and counterpoint!

Answer (score 9):

I'll go for you being

> (Johann Sebastian) [Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bach)

It's a stretch though

> The [received pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) of Bach's name is, in IPA, **bɑːk** (the closest imitation of the German **baχ**)
>
>  He was not himself as such:
>  The received pronunciation could well be written out naively as "barc"
>
>  His part reversed:
>  "barc" reversed spells "crab", a single word
>
>  Two's much too much / together with:
>  A [crab canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_canon) (two words) is an arrangement of two musical lines that are complementary and backward

Comment: This is close, but not correct. Look again at the title.

Comment: Close as in the reasoning is correct but the single word is not?

Comment: The single word is not correct. Some part(s) of the reasoning is/are relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

A stretch probably but could this refer to the musician's

> echo?  Which is almost a noise "reversed"

Comment: Incorrect I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

> Me

You are you, but your part reversed. But maybe it's

> Mi, the syllable used in [solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)

Comment: I'm afraid not!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the one word is

> ENO

that's a musician who's oft rehearsed by himself, because that's his counterpart reversed

> ONE

Two's much too much to

> ONE

Comment: Very creative, but the intended answer is @Tom's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go for the obvious

> solo

Because

> the riddle hints at a musician playing alone, hence solo. Pretty sure I'm wrong and something much more clever was intended, however.

Comment: No, that is incorrect (or at least not what I intended).

Comment: That was my initial thought too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to reluctantly guess:

> Duet

*A musician oft rehearsed:*

> Rehearsing a duet.

*Together with his part reversed:*

> The counter-melody or *secondo* is the bottom part of a duet.

*But he was not himself as such:*

> He cannot be the duet alone.

*A single word - two's much too much:*

> Two people are needed for a duet. I don't understand the 'too much' part though.

I'm not sure my answer is correct, but I thought I would make my best guess.

Comment: Incorrect I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> SOLO

A musician oft rehearsed

> Musicians often sing solo

Together with his part reversed

> I'm not sure about this, but musicians sing the parts they have to in solo

A single word - two's much is too much

> It is a single word and there can't be two solo

**ANOTHER ANSWER**

Is it

> SONG

A musician oft rehearsed

> Musicians often rehearse songs

Together with his part reversed

> Musicians sing the parts they have to in a song

A single word - two's much is too much

> It is a single word

Comment: Neither of these is right,

Answer (score 1):

The single word is:

> Silence

because:

> reversing sounds cancels them.

Probably not what you are looking for, but it appeals to the geek in me.

Comment: No that's not right I'm afraid.